# How to get indices from three.js OBJLoader

Tags: graphics, three.js, webgl

I use three.js OBJLoader to get mesh info, use traverse to get geometry info, but only get position, normal, uv, no indices. Is anyone know how to get indices from OBJLoader?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fus2.png)

```
async function loadObj2(filename) {
    let ret;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            const loader = new OBJLoader();
            loader.load(
                filename,
                (object) => {
                    try{
                        object.traverse((child) => {
                            if(child.isMesh) {
                                let geo = child.geometry;
                                ret = {
                                    position: geo.attributes.position.array,
                                    normal: geo.attributes.normal.array,
                                    uv: geo.attributes.uv.array,
                                };
                            }
                        });
                        ret = 1;
                        resolve(ret);
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        console.log(e);
                        reject(e);
                    }
                },
            (xhr) => {
                console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log( 'An error happened' + error );
                reject();
            }
        )
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`THREE.OBJLoader` always creates non-indexed geometries. Meaning the `index` property of the geometry is `null`.

If you need an index for some reasons, you can compute it manually by using [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices).